# android - change icon of autocomplete_fragment in google maps

Tags: android, google-maps, navigation-drawer

I have an android app using google maps and I wanted a search bar that looks just like the android google maps. Below is my XML code and picture of what I have.

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="8dp">
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/place_autocomplete_fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceAutocompleteFragment"/>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

[image]

The problem is that I have a navigation drawer that opens when you slide from the left. I want to add the "three horizontal lines" to the search bar like google maps so whenever you click that, the navigation drawer opens as shown below.

[image]

So how can I change the "magnifying glass" into "3 horizontal lines" and make the navigation drawer open up on click. Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can find the corresponding `ImageView` and change it's icon and on click event:

```
PlaceAutocompleteFragment placeAutocompleteFragment = (PlaceAutocompleteFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.place_autocomplete_fragment);
ImageView searchIcon = (ImageView)((LinearLayout)placeAutocompleteFragment.getView()).getChildAt(0);

// Set the desired icon
searchIcon.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.yourdrawable));

// Set the desired behaviour on click
searchIcon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "YOUR DESIRED BEHAVIOUR HERE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```